# Make a new field and put 1 for duplicates and 0 for non

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ('road','road','road','highway','house','house'), 
                                   'b' : ('11','23','15','32','17','21')})
```

gives:

df

```
       a    b
0   road    11
1   road    23
2   road    15
3   highway 32
4   house   17
5   house   21
```

I want to make a new field where if according to `a` are duplicates the new files will take 1 otherwise it will take 0.

Here I filter the duplicated values:

```
mask = df['a'].duplicated(keep = False)
df[mask]
```

gives:

```
       a    b
0   road    11
1   road    23
2   road    15
4   house   17
5   house   21
```

Wanted result:

```
       a    b    c
0   road    11   1
1   road    23   1
2   road    15   1
3   highway 32   0
4   house   17   1
5   house   21   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the result of `df['a'].duplicated(keep = False)` to a new column, like:

```
df['c'] = df['a'].duplicated(keep = False)
```

As a result we obtain:

```
>>> df
         a   b      c
0     road  11   True
1     road  23   True
2     road  15   True
3  highway  32  False
4    house  17   True
5    house  21   True
```

or if you want integers:

```
df['c'] = df['a'].duplicated(keep = False).astype(int)
```

which produces the expected:

```
>>> df
         a   b  c
0     road  11  1
1     road  23  1
2     road  15  1
3  highway  32  0
4    house  17  1
5    house  21  1
```